# libvlc_new always returns NULL

Tags: c, libvlc

I try to make the [tutorial example](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/) of libvlc to work.
I installed the vlc SDK via `sudo apt install libvlc-dev` and link against it with `-lvlc`. Compiling and linking finishes without errors or warnings, but whenever I try to initialize VLC and get the instance with `libvlc_new` I get `NULL` as a result.

```c
int
main(int argc, char *argv[argc])
{
  libvlc_instance_t *instance = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
  if (instance == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get VLC instance.\n\t%s\n", libvlc_errmsg());
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // ... usage of libvlc_media etc., but the program never reaches that point.
}
```

Whenever I execute the binary I get the result:

```
$ ./vlc_test some_test_file.mp3
Unable to get VLC instance.
    (null)
```

My compile options are:

```
$ gcc -c main.c -o main.o
$ gcc main.o -o vlc_test -lvlc
```

What am I missing to make libvlc work?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to run this under a debugger and step into libvlc_new if you can, to see what's going wrong, or try reading the source code for libvlc_new too to see if there's anything obvious there.

Comment: regarding: `gcc -c main.c -o main.o`  This will NOT let yhou know of the problems with the code.  Suggest: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c main.c -o main.o`

Comment: Copy the plugins folder to your exe directory. There has been an issue about this here on so. I link it, if I find it. EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22965654/8272795

Comment: just put "-vvv" option to `libvlc_new` and you could see VLC debug output in console

Comment: try `apt get install vlc`, I'm not sure `liblvc-dev` has all necessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

This question is fairly old now, but I had to dig very deep to find the answer to my problem and that was that I needed to set the environment variable `VLC_PLUGIN_PATH` to the `plugins` folder path of the VLC version I linked against.

So in my case (compiling on a Mac):

`VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins`

I hope this helps someone out there struggling to run even the most basic libvlc example.